# Opengl storing all vertex data using 1 buffer

Tags: java, lwjgl

I have created 1 float buffer and 1 vbo with all my vertex data(position, texture coordinates, normals), they are stored as follow:

```
            bf.put(vertices[i].position.x);
            bf.put(vertices[i].position.y);
            bf.put(vertices[i].position.z);
            bf.put(vertices[i].texCoords.x);
            bf.put(vertices[i].texCoords.y);
            bf.put(vertices[i].normals.x);
            bf.put(vertices[i].normals.y);
            bf.put(vertices[i].normals.z);
```

How can I pass them to the shader using glVertexAttribPointer ?

Is it possible to do something like:

```
 glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

            glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
            glVertexAttribPointer(/*arguments for sending position*/);
 glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);

            glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
            glVertexAttribPointer(/*arguments for sending texture coordinates*/);

glEnableVertexAttribArray(2);

            glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
            glVertexAttribPointer(/*arguments for sending normals*/);
```

?

If it is, then please help me understand glVertexAttribPointer and what arguments I should put.

Comment: For the arguments, see the [documentation](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/glVertexAttribPointer.xhtml)

Comment: I have read the documentation but I can't get it to work using a vbo, I need an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data arrangement you are using for your attributes is typically called "interleaved", and is in fact the recommended way of storing multiple attributes in a VBO. It favors local data access because all attributes for a vertex are next to each other in memory, which in turn tends to result in high cache hit rates.

Let's look at the signature of `glVertexAttribPointer()`, and then explain the arguments in some more detail. I intentionally won't copy the explanation from the documentation, in the hope that alternate wording will help you understand them better. In LWJGL, it is defined as:

```
static void glVertexAttribPointer(
    int index, int size, int type, boolean normalized,
    int stride, long pointerOffset)
```

- `index`: Location of the vertex attribute in the vertex shader, as specified with `glBindAttribLocation()`, obtained with `glGetAttribLocation()`, or specified in the shader code with the `location` layout qualifier.
- `size`: Number of components in the attribute. E.g. 3 for positions with 3 coordinates, 2 for texture coordinates with 2 components, etc.
- `type`: Type of attribute. Mostly `GL_FLOAT`.
- `normalized`: Does not matter for float attributes, read up on it if you ever start using integer type attributes.
- `stride`: Spacing in bytes between subsequent vertices. Unless you have padding between vertices (which is fairly rare), this is the same as the size of a vertex in bytes.
- `pointerOffset`: This has "pointer" in its name for historical reasons, but is in fact the offset in bytes of the first occurrence of the attribute relative to the start of the buffer. In an interleaved arrangement, this corresponds to the offset of the attribute within the vertex, in bytes.

In your case, `stride` will be 32, since each vertex consists of 8 float components, which are 4 bytes each.

The `pointerOffset` is 0 for the first attribute, and then the relative byte offset for all the rest of them, which results in 12 and 20 for the remaining two attributes.

This makes the calls for your example:

```
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 8 * 4, 0);
glVertexAttribPointer(1, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 8 * 4, 3 * 4);
glVertexAttribPointer(2, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 8 * 4, (3 + 2) * 4);
```